# Print cricular single linked list recursively in C

Tags: c, linked-list, circular-list

I should work recursively on a circular single linked list in C, my problem is, being recursive, I'm not able to print the list correctly and I got some problems accessing to the tmp->key in the display() function (segmentation fault due to illegal access) when I push more than 1 element and I want to display the list later. Both tmp and list are declared as `struct node* tmp = NULL;` and `struct node* list = NULL;`
Main extract:

```
    case 8:
tmp = list;
        if (tmp->next == tmp)
    printf("\n%d\n", tmp->key);
else
            display (list, tmp);
        break;
```

Function:

```
void display (struct node* head, struct node* tmp){

    if (head != NULL){
        if (tmp != head){
            printf ("%d ", tmp->key);
            tmp = tmp->next;
            display(head, tmp);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you manage only circular list having **one** cell ?

Comment: @bruno What do you mean? if you mean just one field (key) then yes, it's required just one field.

Comment: no, I ask because I only see the case where *list->next == list* / *tmp->next == tmp*, so a circular list having one cell, you do not detect a circular list of two cells where *list->next != list* but *list->next->next == list* etc

Answer (score 0):

The design suggests that `tmp` should point to an existing node in the list.

If `tmp` is `NULL`, you'll have to check for that condition in `display()` to avoid a segmentation fault.

You will also want to check whether `tmp` is `NULL` ahead of this code:

```c
        if (tmp->next == tmp)
```

Comment: I don't need to check if tmp it's NULL because i assign the head of the list tot tmp before calling display, can explicit where I should edit my code please? because I really don't get it

Comment: Please submit as much code as possible to allow another SO user to compile the test.  You mention above that 'i assign the head of the list tot tmp before calling display', but your question only says 'struct node* tmp = NULL' and 'struct node* list = NULL'.  This implies that both tmp and list are NULL.  The more detail you provide the better equipped I or someone else will be to answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
void display (struct node *head, struct node *this){

    if (!head) return;
    if (!this) return;

    printf ("%d ", this->key);

    if (this->next == head) return;
    display(head, this->next);
}
```

---

And, the tail-recursion is removed by the compiler (gcc -O4 -S):

---

```
.globl  display
        .type   display, @function
display:
.LFB24:
        .cfi_startproc
        pushq   %rbp
        .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
        .cfi_offset 6, -16
        movq    %rdi, %rbp
        pushq   %rbx
        .cfi_def_cfa_offset 24
        .cfi_offset 3, -24
        subq    $8, %rsp
        .cfi_def_cfa_offset 32
        testq   %rdi, %rdi
        je      .L1
        testq   %rsi, %rsi
        movq    %rsi, %rbx
        jne     .L4
        jmp     .L1
        .p2align 4,,10
        .p2align 3
.L12:
        testq   %rbx, %rbx
        je      .L1
.L4:
        movl    8(%rbx), %edx
        xorl    %eax, %eax
        movl    $.LC0, %esi
        movl    $1, %edi
        call    __printf_chk
        movq    (%rbx), %rbx
        cmpq    %rbp, %rbx
        jne     .L12
.L1:
        addq    $8, %rsp
        .cfi_def_cfa_offset 24
        popq    %rbx
        .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
        popq    %rbp
        .cfi_def_cfa_offset 8
        ret
        .cfi_endproc
.LFE24:
        .size   display, .-display
```